# Python regex search AND split

Tags: python, regex

In PHP one can use the function `preg_match` with the flag `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` in order to search a regex patter within a string and know what follows and what comes first. For example, given the string `aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff`, I'd like to match-split  `r'ddd'` and have:

```
before = 'aaa bbb ccc '
match = 'ddd'
after = ' eee fff'
```

How to do this in python? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `re.split()` but you need to put parentheses around the pattern so as to save the match:

```
>>> re.split('(ddd)', 'aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff', 1)
['aaa bbb ccc ', 'ddd', ' eee fff']
```

but in this case you don't need a regex at all:

```
>>> 'aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff'.partition('ddd')
('aaa bbb ccc ', 'ddd', ' eee fff')
```

**Edit:** I should probably also mention that with re.split you will get all of the matching groups, so you need to be prepared for that or use non-capturing groups everywhere you would otherwise use parentheses for precedence:

```
>>> re.split('(d(d)d)', 'aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff', 1)
['aaa bbb ccc ', 'ddd', 'd', ' eee fff']
```

Comment: Did not know you can do that with `re.split()`. Thanks